# Regression output vs overall omnibus test when having specific hypotheses about interaction

Tags: mixed-model, categorical-data, interaction, regression-coefficients

I'm having a mixed model with 5 repeated measurements (time is categorical) and 2 groups, and I'm interested in the interaction between these two. The omnbibus LRT test says that the interaction is not statistically signficant (p = 0.10). However I'm interested in comparing the differences in changes  of the outcome variable between the groups at specific time points (e.g. timepoint 1 vs 2, timepoint 1 vs 3, time point 3 vs 5)... So in my undersanding I have ''planned contrasts''. Some of the regression coefficents of these single interaction terms in the output are actually significant. Does it mean I can look at the p-values of these terms, even if the overall interaction is not statistically significant?

I hope my question is clear, let me know if you need more information. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can evaluate pre-planned contrasts (not based on seeing the results of the model) without a significant overall effect. You must, however, correct for [multiple comparisons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem). If you only had 5 pre-planned pairwise comparisons and used a p < 0.05 criterion for significance for each of them separately, you would have nearly a 23% chance (`1-(0.95)^5`) of at least one false-positive result. For this type of study, it seems that you would need to control the [family-wise error rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family-wise_error_rate#Controlling_procedures) so that the probability of *no* false-positive is less than 5%.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful!